# Can I save and query tags in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

What are the ways to save tags to records in firebase. For example I have a user who has favourites and he/she can add multiple tags to the favourite. I would like to be able to query by one or more of the tags?

This is the basic structure

```
Users{
 favourites: {
   fav_1:{
        tags:[tag1,tag2,tag3,...]
   }
   fav_2:{
        tags:[tag1,tag2,...]
   }

   .....
 }
```

}

Answer (score 8):

In Firebase (like on most NoSQL databases), you'll often have to model your data for the way your applications wants to use it.

Your current model is great for finding the list of tags (fav_1, fav_2) for a specific user. It is however not so great for finding out the list of users for a specific tag. To allow the latter query, add an inverted lookup list to your data model:

```
Tags: {
    fav_1: {
        User1: true,
        User2: true
    }
    ...
}
```

By combining this with your original model, you can look up the list of tags for a user as well as the list of users for a tag.

For a great introduction to NoSQL data modeling, see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I want to be able to save multiple tags to a favourite I've edited the question for a more clear description.

Comment: Hi Puf. I was wondering if in a scenario like `post`s are able to have `tag`s, is it correct that every `post` has a `tags` (consisting of `tag_id`s) and there should be a separate `tags` node that contains the the list of `tag_id`s which also have the `post_id`s associated with them? (i.e. `post - post_id - tags[]`, `tags - tag_id - posts []`) -- I've taken a look around and this is the simplest structure I could think of so far, was aiming to have the tags be used for searching posts as well (similar to Stack Overflow's)

Comment: I normally model such categorization problems by storing the relation in both directions, so from post to its categories and from categories to its post. See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value. Feel free to open a new question to discuss further btw, as comments are subideal for showing data structure. :-)

Comment: Thanks Puf! I've actually taken a look at your answer that you linked, and managed to come up with the relation I mentioned. So everything seems as simple as that. I'll be sure to put in a question (with additional details) if I have further questions. Cheers! :)